# Как заставить объект типа Т использовать поле f_version?

Tags: c#, типы-данных

Объекты data содержат поля f_version.

В функциях вместо конкретных типов объектов использую универсальный T.

Но универсальный тип T не содержит поле f_version.

Как заставить объект типа  Т использовать поле f_version?

```
public class BF_Load
    {
        private int Version;

        public void Save<T>(object data, string filepath)
            ...

            Version = ((T)data).f_version;
```

Comment: А что должен делать код, если тип `T` не содержит поля `f_version`?

Answer (score 1):

Можно ввести базовый тип (я предпочитаю интерфейсы):

```
public interface IVersionable
{
    int f_version { get; }
}
```

Затем ограничить дженерик-параметр в метод `Save` этим типом:

```
public void Save<T>(object data, string filepath)
    where T : IVersionable
{
    ...
    Version = ((T)data).f_version;
    ...
}
```

Приведение на самом деле ни к чему, параметр `data` можно объявить сразу типом `T`:

```
public void Save<T>(T data, string filepath)
    where T : IVersionable
{
    ...
    Version = data.f_version;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял вопрос, но возможно, Вы имеете ввиду это:

```
public void Save<T>(object data, string filepath)
{
   var target = (T)Convert.ChangeType(data, typeof(T));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего, если Вам необходимо ссылаться на конкретное поле, Ваш метод не совсем не такой уж Generic. Так ли уж необходимо чтобы данный метод был универсальным? Если нет (что более всего вероятно), то рекомендую заменить тип параметра data на тип, в котором было объявлено поле f_version.

Если Вы всё же Вам такое решение не подходит, Вы можете воспользоваться одним из предложенных решений ниже:

a) Добавить уточнение к типу T:

```
public void Save<T>(object data, string filepath) where T: BaseType
```

где BaseType это тип, в котором объявлено поле f_version

b) Передавать в метод Save анонимную функцию

```
public void Save<T>(object data, string filepath, Action<T,BF_Load> action = null)
{
    if(action != null)
    {
        action((T)data, this);
    }
    ...
}
```

Сам метод вызывать следующим образом:

```
bfLoad.Save(data, filepath, (t, bf) => { bf.Version = t.f_version });
```

Однако в данном случае придется изменить доступность поля Version

c) Воспользоваться рефлексией:

```
Version = (int)typeof(T).GetField("f_version", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(data);
```

Однако я настоятельно рекомендую в первую очередь пересмотреть необходимость метода Save оставаться универсальным.